# using method that take variable number of parameters

Tags: java

I am trying to make a method that build new object of the class (PhoneBook)  using different constructors according to the number of parameters ,, but it  gives an error

(      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 )

```
public static PhoneBook createObjects(String fName,String lName,String num,String...optional)
{
    n++;    
    if (optional[0]==null)
        ArrayOfObjects[n]=new PhoneBook(fName,lName,num);
    else if (optional[1]==null)
        ArrayOfObjects[n]=new PhoneBook(fName,lName,num,optional[0]);

    return ArrayOfObjects[n];   
}
```

Comment: @Vipar maybe a `PhoneBook` array declared somewhere else in OP's code (not relevant to the question)?

Comment: @Vipar  actually I start n  with  0  ,  but  why this array never take values ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking whether `optional[0] == null`, you should examine `optional.length` to determine if the optional parameter is present.

The same goes for `optional[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking `optional[0]` and `optional[1]` here, you should check to `optional.length`. Also, keep in mind that `optional` itself may well be `null`, so something like:

```
if(optional != null) {
    if(optional.length > 0) {
        // I now know that optional has at least one element in it, and optional[0] should be valid, though I don't know that it is non-null.
        if(optional.length > 1) {
            // I now know that optional[1] is valid, though I do not know it is non-null.
        }
    }
}
```

if you NEED non-null:

```
if(optional.length > 0 && optional[0] != null)
```

The second part, `optional[0] != null` will only be called if the first evaluates to true.